# Linux: execute a command when network connection is restored

Tags: linux, bash

I have a linux box connected to a router via an ethernet cable. 
The cable is never unplugged and the linux box is always on. 
My goal is to have a command executed on the linux box every time the router is rebooted.

This question is quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548088/ubuntu-wait-for-network-link-up-and-execute-a-bash-command) but the suggested solution doesn't seem to work. 
More specifically:

- the command 
  `inotifywait -e modify /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier; echo 'Change detected'` does never detect a change (even in the case the cable is unplugged from the pc), because according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672414/inotify-add-watch-fails-on-sys-class-net-eth0-operstate?answertab=votes#tab-top) the command `inotifywait` does not work in `/sys`
- the command (suggested in a comment) `inotifywait -e modify /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon` does not detect any change when the router is rebooted

Comment: You may better help from SuperUser.. voting to move there

Comment: How  do I move the question to SuperUser?

Comment: what is the reason for this? do you want to check if your external IP has changed?

Comment: Actually, this question belongs on [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and I would love to see the answers that wonderful community would come up with for this question.

Comment: @Ixer: the reason is that the pc runs a vpn client: when the router goes down and then up again I want to restart the vpn connection automatically (the router is shut down every night and turned on every morning, while the pc is always on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a script after the linux box gets connected using `up`
(requires `ifplugd` to be installed )

```
 #/etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    up /etc/network/yourscript.sh
```

However, there keep in mind that if you disconnect the cable (and plug in in after a while), the script also starts even though the router might not have been restarted.

--edit--

alternatively , place your script in

`/etc/network/if-up.d/`
(make sure it is executable and restart networking after changes.)

Comment: @Ixer: I already tried with just "up" and it didn't work. Maybe "post-up" was the right one: I'll give it a try

Comment: for some reason it doesnt work on my ubuntu machine either, even though this used to be the correct way. (i blame 'networkmanager', it sucks. `wicd` has better scripting options  ).   Try putting  your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

Comment: If an interface is in `/etc/network/interfaces`, then it is not managed by NetworkManager (after NM is restarted). From my experiments, `up` and `down` script are triggered only if the interface is managed by `ifup/ifdown`. I have been able to get this installing the `ifplug` daemon. I will test that for a few days to see if it works.

Comment: @Ixer: it looks like it works, provided the ifplug daemon is install and manages eth0. So, if you edit your answer adding this (and changing `post-up` to simply `up`, then I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Linux distribution on that router the correct way of running a command at startup/reboot is to create a startup script, or add the command to /etc/rc.local

Comment: Adding the command to /etc/rc.local is the easiest way - it's the last thing to run in all of your runlevels before providing a login prompt.

Comment: there is most likely no access to this if it is a simple router. The goal was to execute a command on the linux box, not on the router itself.