# How to set up a udev rule for ETH "link down"/"link up"?

Tags: linux, udev

I like to switch on a green LED(connected through GPIOs), when eth0 is connected. When disconnected I like to switch the green LED of and a red one on.

Thought that udev is maybe the right place for it. I created the simple demo rule:

```
KERNEL=="eth0", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/sbin/set_BSPleds eth0 on"
```

This rule should call a script when the eth0 is added. It was never executed.
After I was looking to the udev monitor by entering "udevadm monitor -k -u" at the shell. There were no events coming when I unplug/plug the lan cable.

```
root@sama5d3xek:/etc/udev/rules.d# udevadm monitor -k -uh0
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

root@sama5d3xek:/etc/udev/rules.d#
```

Seems that there are no uevents for eth0. The ethernet driver is provided my ATMEL. I am building a custom Linux by the help of Yocto.

My question is, how to get the "link down"/"link up" events to udev?
If it does not works with udev, what alternative way is the best?

Comment: This question could better be asked at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: feel free to create a similar one  and I will link to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethernet devices are devices, but connections are not.

You could *trace* connection through `/dev/xconsole`, `dmesg` or `/var/log/kern.log`.

#### Sample, using `rsyslog`:

You could (as root):

```
echo ':msg, contains, "Link is" |/run/netlink' >/etc/rsyslog.d/netlinkstate.conf
mkfifo /run/netlink
chgrp user /run/netlink
chmod 640 /run/netlink
service rsyslog force-reload
```

Then, logged as *user*, simply:

```
read line < /run/netlink
```

will wait for input from fifo, then hold until something happen.

```
state=${line#*Link is } eventtime=${line%% $HOSTNAME*}
echo $eventtime $state
2016-11-21T17:40:50.956181+01:00 Down
```

or

```
echo $eventtime $state
2016-11-21T17:40:50.956181+01:00 Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx

echo $eventtime ${state%% *}
2016-11-21T17:40:50.956181+01:00 Up
```

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use timeout for emptying fifo and read only last entry:

```
while read -t .01 entry </run/netlink;do line="$entry";done
state=${line#*Link is }
eventtime=${line%% $HOSTNAME*}
shortstate=${state%% *}
```

**Nota:** I've used `/run` to store fifo. This could be not the better place as this won't exist on next reboot.

Comment: looks like I have to create a script which is started through systemV. This is permanently reading on dmesg and greping eth*?

Comment: Or through `if-up` or `if-down` script. This depend on your Linux distro.

Comment: There is no common "distro". It is a embeeded Linux.

Comment: I've posted a more detailled answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40678535/1765658

Comment: Your edit was rejected because there is a lot of *bad practices* in it... Tracking an event would better be done by interacting with syslog. I suggest you post your proposed script as a new question.

Comment: As you're speaking about *no common distro*, I've posted a little sample using `rsyslog`.

Comment: my sample worked without rsyslog. The code works fine on my build machine. rRsyslog not installed on the embeeded linux system. Maybe someone knows good way to handle the events without extra tools/software

Comment: You could follow `/var/log/kern.log` or `/proc/kmsg`, but don't pool event!

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, it seems one can't use udev for this.

[Ubuntu: wait for network link up and execute a bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548088/#24562724) suggests

```
inotifywait -e modify /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier; echo 'Change detected'
```

(Currently, / is on nfs for my box, so I can't really say if it will work.)

In other posts, there are some concerns about using the inotify API on /sys: [inotify_add_watch fails on /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672414/#26674239) .

I think the Right Way(TM) do do this would be to use the netlink(7) API, preferably through a daemon such as netplugd.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Even if you're `/` is on *nfs*, `/sys` is still mounted from your kernel. So this must work (or not work) same as on other `/` rootfs based... (read remarks about *inotify* on `/sys` partition.